# How to count frequency in each column, corresponding to first column in perl

Tags: perl

I have a input like this.

```
a x1
a x1
a y1
b x1
b y1
b z1
c y1
c z1
```

Want a output like this

```
a = 3, x1= 2, y1= 1, z1= 0     
b = 3, x1= 1, y1= 1, z1=1    
c =2, x1=0, y1=1, z1=1
```

I want to make a perl program for this, but do not know .

Please help..

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty simple homework problem (which is why this has been downvoted a couple of times, no doubt), but it's a good way to show the power of hashes if you're struggling with that.

Let's break this down. You want to classify things by the first column (and count the number of occurrences), counting the associated data. Hashes are perfect for this.

Let's assume that the final hash will look something like this:

```
{
    'a' => {
        '*count' => 3,
        'x1' => 2,
        'y1' => 1,
    },
    . . .
}
```

(where `'*count'` is a string that should never appear in your data) and that your output will look like your specification.

Parsing the data is pretty simple.

```
my $hash = {};
my $count = '*count';
for( @lines ) {
    chomp;
    my ($x, $y) = split( /\s+/ );
    $hash->{$x}->{$count}++;
    $hash->{$x}->{$y}++;
}
```

Printing it out is just as simple:

```
for my $x ( sort keys %{$hash} ) {
    my @output = ( sprintf( '%s = %d', $x, $hash->{$x}->{$count} ) );
    for my $y ( qw{ x1 y1 z1 } ) {
        push( @output, sprintf( '%s = %d', $y, $hash->{$x}->{$y} ) );
    }
    print join( ', ', @output ) . "\n";
}
```

Note that if, say, `$hash->{'c'}->{'z1'}` doesn't exist, the value returned will still be 0. You can do the additional checking with `exists` if you like, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I would personally avoid embedding the count in the hash - relying on 'something that never appears' is poor program logic. Why not instead use `values` on the subhashes?

Comment: ... or a separate `count_of` hash? It's not like you're paying by the byte.